# Command for colouring text bits and wrap them in single quotation marks

Tags: macros, color, quotation

For inline quotes, I need **UK English single quotation mark glyphs**:

> ‘To be or not to be,’ Hamlet said.

Also, I need the text - but not the quotation marks - **colored gray**.

I have tried looking at the [dirtytalk](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/dirtytalk) package that seems to allow for customizing the quotation marks. But I might need to create a customized command if I wish to also have the gray coloring so that I can use it with one command such as:

> `\inlinequotehere{To be or not to be,}  Hamlet said.`

Is there a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by defining two things:

- An appropriate colour, and
- `\inlinequotehere` that would insert the quotes, and the text using the above-defined colour.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{quotecolor}{black!50}% Allows one to use quotecolor elsewhere in the document in a consistent way
\newcommand{\inlinequotehere}[1]{`\textcolor{quotecolor}{#1}'}

\begin{document}

\inlinequotehere{To be or not to be,} Hamlet said.

\inlinequotehere{To be or not to be\textcolor{black}{,}} Hamlet said.

\end{document}
```